# How to find out first character index in my Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have a textbox, I need to enter only alphabet in the starting of textbox; no integers, no special characters.... What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the script

```
function fnalpha() 
{ 
    if (event.keycode >= 65 && event.keycode <= 90 ||
        event.keycode >= 97 && event.keycode <= 122) event.returnValue = true;
    else event.returnValue = false; 
}
```

In the source of textbox call this method `onkeypress="return fnalpha()"`

I tried like this... worked properly...

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing this client side, you could use an `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` control in the following manner.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="inputBox" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
    runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="inputBox" 
    ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z].*" 
    ErrorMessage="Input must start with a letter" />
```

Server side, you could simply check the first character by using `char.IsLetter`.

```
bool isValid = char.IsLetter(inputBox.Text[0]);
```

Comment: regularexpression validator is at server side, but i am using javascript validations only... then how to get that value from textbox which is in asp.net form

Comment: Actually it's both, it will generate javascript markup, and if the client has javascript disabled, it will also check server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TextBox.Validated` event and match the content with `RegEx`.
Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Using javascripts match() method and the following RegularExpression should do the trick

```
^[a-zA-Z].*
```

Here is a short example of how to implement the match method with the regex above

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validate()
  {
      var textBoxToValidate = document.getElementById('Text1');
      if(textBoxToValidate.value.match('^[a-zA-Z].*'))
      {
          alert('Is valid');
      }  
      else
      {
          alert('Is invalid');
      }
  }
</script>

<input id="Text1" type="text" />
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="validate()" />
```

Comment: can u explain about match() method... how can i achieve this with match()... i dont want to use serverside validators

Comment: For good measure I just wanted to point out that the the RegularExpressionValidator has clientside validation as well. I used the match method because of the javascript tag.

Comment: in the script
function fnalpha()
{
if(event.keycode>=65 && event.keycode<=90 || event.keycode>=97&&event.keycode<=122)
         event.retrunValue=true;
else
         event.returnValue=false;

in the source of textbox, call this method 
onkeypress="return fnalpha()";

i tried like this... worked properly...